# Remove table row, subtract from sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite new with jQuery, the following code is a collage of 2 different codes I found to achieve my objective

I have a table with a an image that when clicked it removes a table row, that is the first part of the below code.

The second part of the script finds the sum of all the table rows

**I am trying to make it so that when you remove a row the sum also changes accordingly. So when you remove a table row the amount in that table row will be subtracted from the total. I need the sum to change according to the row you delete**

jQuery part that removes the table row

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('table#FeatureMatrix td a.delete').click(function()
        {

            {
                var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                var data = 'id=' + id ;
                var parent = $(this).parent().parent();




                       parent.fadeOut('slow', function() 
                                           {$(this).remove();});
                    return false;       
            }



        });
```

Part of jQuery that calculates the sum of all table rows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //this calculates values automatically 
     calculateSum();

     $(".txt").live("keydown keyup", function() {
        calculateSum();
     });
});
        function calculateSum() {
            var sum = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".txt").each(function() {
                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);

                }
                else if (this.value.length != 0){

               }
            });
            $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
        }
```

If somebody wants to see the example page on the web this is the link  http://webiceberg.net/Prices.php, you can also view the source of the page if you need more detail on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call calculateSum() when you delete the row (tidied the code up a bit as well!):

```
$('table#FeatureMatrix td a.delete').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var data = 'id=' + id ;
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        calculateSum();
    });

    return false;                   
});
```

Note that it has to be done after the $(this).remove() inside the callback otherwise you will call calculate before actually removing the row.

If you are concerned about it calling `calculateSum` directly then fire a custom event and listen for that and then recalculate:

```
$('table#FeatureMatrix td a.delete').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var data = 'id=' + id ;
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $.event.trigger("rowDeleted"); // fire custom event
    });

    return false;                   
});
```

Then listen for this event:

```
$('#sum').bind('rowDeleted', function() {    // listen for custom event
    calculateSum();
});
```

Comment: The calculateSum function will not be visible there. Also, it does not seperate concerns too well... what happens when another metric needs to be calculated or a row added?

Comment: Looks like calculateSum is global to me. I have added an edit that should separate the concerns.

Comment: ok so i poped it into my code and it works like a charm , and thanks for cleaning up the code for me , you made my day coz i had to show this to a potential client tonight ,   thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$("table#FeatureMatrix").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    calculateSum();
});
```

This will recalculate the sum each time the table is modified (It will work for rows added too)

Comment: Ok i tried this as well and i added it just before closing document ready function and it also works like a charm , thanks man